# Calcuation from columns inside select statement

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, select, node-sqlite3

I have a sqlite3 table `ACCOUNTS` which contains four columns `NAME`, `SCORE`, `START_TIME` and `CURRENT_TIME`. `START_TIME` and `CURRENT_TIME` are in milliseconds (since 1970). Now I would like to calculate from each row the `SCORE / ((CURRENT_TIME - START_TIME) / (1000*60*60*24))`, that means the average score per day. The result should be ordered according to this average score per day (descending).

I though about something similar like

```
SELECT NAME name, SCORE score FROM ACCOUNTS ORDER BY score DESC, name ASC
```

but I don't know how to incorporate the above calculation.

Comment: Why don't you `select *, SCORE / ((CURRENT_TIME - START_TIME) / (1000*60*60*24)) from ...`. You already have the expression that you want to calculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have this quite sorted out already, and just miss an expression that gives you the current date/time as epoch. In SQLIte, you can use `strftime('%s', 'now')` for this - this returns a number of *seconds* since unix epoch, not milliseconds, so a little adjustement is needed:

```
select 
    name, 
    score, 
    score / (strftime('%s', 'now') - starttime / 1000) / 60 / 60 / 24 avg_daily_score
from accounts
order by avg_daily_score desc
```